# Dice game doesn't stop when anyone reaches 100. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, dice

I am freshman in the university and learning Java. We have a project to do as a homework. We need to create a dice game. I'll first share the rules for the game and then post my code and problems I have with that.
Player & CPU throw dices the one with the bigger dice starts the game. You start rolling a dice unless you say stop. (HOLD) When you hold it, you add your temporary safe score to your safe and loose your turn. If you throw 1 you will lose your turn and gain nothing. Same apply for the CPU. First one to reach 100 wins the game.
Now with my code : The game doesn't stop when anyone reaches 100. And also I don't think my CPU A.I is not good i might need help about that too. Also when the first dices is equal (the ones determine who will start the game) the game doesn't start.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
  public static void main (String args[]) {


    int player_safe = 0;
    int cpu_safe = 0;
    int player_temp = 0;
    int cpu_temp = 0;
    boolean cpu_turn = false;
    boolean player_turn = false;

    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    System.out.println ( "Enter your name : " ) ;
    String player = name.nextLine();
    System.out.println ( "Dice Game" ) ;
    System.out.println ( "RULES" ) ;
    System.out.println ( "" ) ;
    System.out.println ( "If a 1 is rolled player's turn ends and earns no points." ) ;
    System.out.println ( "If player chooses to hold, player will gain all the points in that turn and loose turn." ) ;
    System.out.println ( "" ) ;
    System.out.println ( "To determine who will start the game " +player+ " and CPU will roll a dice. The one who rolls higher will start the game." ) ;
    System.out.println ( "" ) ;
    System.out.println ( "If you are ready to roll a dice press 1." ) ;




    // ROLL A DICE TO DETERMINE WHO WILL START THE GAME

    int dice;
    int dice_player = 0;
    int dice_cpu = 0;
    Scanner begin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int player_roll = begin.nextInt();
    if (player_roll == 1 ) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
        dice_player = (int) (Math.random()*6+1) ;
        dice_cpu = (int) (Math.random()*6+1) ;  
        System.out.println ( "You rolled " +dice_player ) ; 
        System.out.println ( "CPU rolled " +dice_cpu ); 
        if ( dice_player > dice_cpu) {
          System.out.println ("Player starts the game.");
          cpu_turn = false;
          player_turn = true; }
        else if ( dice_player < dice_cpu) {
          System.out.println ("CPU starts the game.");
          player_turn = false;
          cpu_turn=true; };
        if ( dice_player == dice_cpu ) {
          System.out.println ("It is a tie! Re-rolling...");
          dice_player = (int) (Math.random()*6+1) ;
          dice_cpu = (int) (Math.random()*6+1) ;  
          System.out.println ( "You rolled " +dice_player ) ; 
          System.out.println ( "CPU rolled " +dice_cpu );  }
      }
    //MAIN WHILE
    while ( player_safe <= 100 || cpu_safe <=100 ) {
       // PLAYER TURN WHILE
      while ( player_turn == true && cpu_turn == false ) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("Roll or hold? (1/0) ") ;
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        if ( choice == 1 ) {
        dice = (int) (Math.random()*6+1) ;
             if (dice == 1 ) {
          player_temp = 0; 
          player_turn = false;
          cpu_turn= true;
          System.out.println ("You rolled 1 you earned nothing.") ; } 
        else {
          System.out.println ("You rolled " +dice ) ;
          player_temp += dice;
          System.out.println ("Your temporary safe: " +player_temp ); }
      }
        else if ( choice == 0 ) {
          player_safe += player_temp ;
          player_turn = false;
          cpu_turn = true;
          player_temp = 0;
          System.out.println ("You have " +player_safe+ " points in your safe." ); } }

        // CPU TURN WHILE
        while ( player_turn == false && cpu_turn == true ) {
          dice = (int) (Math.random()*6+1) ; 
          if (dice == 1 ) {
            cpu_temp = 0;
            cpu_turn = false;
            player_turn = true;
            System.out.println ("CPU rolled 1 and earned nothing."); } 
          else {
           cpu_temp +=dice;
           if ( cpu_safe < 20 && cpu_temp >= 15 ) {
             cpu_safe += cpu_temp; 
             cpu_turn = false;
             player_turn = true;
             cpu_temp = 0; }
           if ( cpu_safe <= 40 && cpu_temp >= 12 && cpu_safe - 10 <= player_safe ) {
             cpu_safe += cpu_temp; 
             cpu_turn = false;
             player_turn = true;
             cpu_temp = 0; }
            if ( cpu_safe <= 60 && cpu_temp >= 10 ) {
             cpu_safe += cpu_temp; 
             cpu_turn = false;
             player_turn = true;
             cpu_temp = 0; }
            if ( cpu_safe <= 70 && cpu_temp >= 12 ) {
             cpu_safe += cpu_temp; 
             cpu_turn = false;
             player_turn = true;
             cpu_temp = 0; }
            if ( cpu_safe <= 80 && cpu_temp >= 6 ) {
             cpu_safe += cpu_temp; 
             cpu_turn = false;
             player_turn = true;
             cpu_temp = 0; }
           if ( cpu_safe <= 100 && ( cpu_safe > player_safe ) && cpu_temp >= 5 ) {
             cpu_safe += cpu_temp;
             cpu_turn= false;
             player_turn = true;
             cpu_temp = 0; }
           if ( cpu_safe <= 100 && ( cpu_safe < player_safe ) && cpu_temp >= 12 ) {
             cpu_safe += cpu_temp;
             cpu_turn= false;
             player_turn = true;
             cpu_temp = 0; }

           System.out.println ("rolled "+dice) ;
           System.out.println ("safe "+cpu_safe) ; }
        }



      //while safe
     //while turn
  } // main
} //class
  }}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger =)

Comment: maybe some classes too..

Comment: What do you mean by you need help with the computer AI? Is there strategy to this game, or is it just a simple dice game?

Comment: I'll just leave this article here for anyone that's interested - http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=460

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's wrong with my code?

Such an open-ended question.  It deserves a lengthy answer.

Whenever you create any Java application, you should keep in mind the [model / view / controller architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), abbreviated MVC.  Almost every Java application requires a model, a view, and a controller.

Here's a data model for your game.  The first model class is the PlayerModel.

```
public class PlayerModel {

    private static final int maxScore = 100;

    private static final String computerName = "Computer";

    private int numberOfRolls;
    private int score;
    private int tempScore;

    private String name;

    public PlayerModel(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numberOfRolls = 0;
        this.score = 0;
        this.tempScore = 0;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRolls() {
        return numberOfRolls;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public int getTempScore() {
        return tempScore;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static int getMaxScore() {
        return maxScore;
    }

    public static String getComputerName() {
        return computerName;
    }

    public boolean addTempScore(int count) {
        if (count == 1) {
            this.tempScore = 0;
            this.numberOfRolls = 0;
            return false;
        } else {
            this.tempScore += count;
            this.numberOfRolls++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void addScore() {
        this.score += this.tempScore;
        this.tempScore = 0;
        this.numberOfRolls = 0;
    }

    public boolean isWinner() {
        return (getScore() >= maxScore);
    }

    public boolean isComputer() {
        return (getName().equals(computerName));
    }
}
```

You would have one instance of this class for each player.

The next model class is the DiceGameModel.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DiceGameModel {

    private static final int maxPlayers = 4;

    private int playerNumber;

    private List<PlayerModel> players;

    public DiceGameModel() {
        this.players = new ArrayList<PlayerModel>();
        this.playerNumber = -1;
    }

    public int getPlayerNumber() {
        return playerNumber;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlayers() {
        return players.size();
    }

    public static int getMaxPlayers() {
        return maxPlayers;
    }

    public void addPlayer(PlayerModel player) {
        this.players.add(player);
    }

    public void setPlayerNumber(int playerNumber) {
        this.playerNumber = playerNumber;
    }

    public PlayerModel getNextPlayer() {
        this.playerNumber++;
        this.playerNumber %= getNumberOfPlayers();
        return getCurrentPlayer(playerNumber);
    }

    public PlayerModel getCurrentPlayer(int playerNumber) {
        return players.get(playerNumber);
    }

}
```

There would be one instance of this class.  This class contains all of the information necessary to play the game.

The view is your interaction with the user(s) using System.out and Scanner.  You should isolate this code in one or more classes.

The controller is what ties the model to the view.  The controller would be responsible for starting the game, determining which player wins, determining what System.out methods and Scanner methods to execute, and whatever else is necessary for the mechanics of the game.

I've provided you with a model.  I believe that you can come up with the view and the controller yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things to think about:

1) What happens when the player and the CPU tie twice in a row (1/36 chance)?  Is there a better way to restructure that initial roll?

2) Will the game end if the player's score is 101 and the CPU's score is 98?  Look at the exit condition in the while clause.

3) Is there a way to use functions and OO-style design to make this code cleaner and more readable?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop needs to be fixed; `while ( player_safe <= 100 || cpu_safe <=100 )` means while one of the scores is under 100. You have to change that to an `&&` to say while both scores are under 100.

Also, I agree with other posters that you may want to use abstraction to break up your code into definitions. I'm not sure what all you've covered, but using functions will make your code cleaner and easier to read.

Additionally, it sounds like you need a loop. If the dice are equal, how do you determine who goes first?

Answer (score 0):

A man who fish's does not first throw his rod, he must first locate water.

Start with the algorithm, not code.